# Retrieve 2 last posts for each category

Tags: sql, optimization, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Lets say I have 2 tables: blog_posts and categories. Each blog post belongs to only ONE category, so there is basically a foreign key between the 2 tables here.

I would like to retrieve the 2 lasts posts from each category, is it possible to achieve this in a single request?
GROUP BY would group everything and leave me with only one row in each category. But I want 2 of them.

It would be easy to perform 1 + N query (N = number of category). First retrieve the categories. And then retrieve 2 posts from each category.

I believe it would also be quite easy to perform M queries (M = number of posts I want from each category). First query selects the first post for each category (with a group by). Second query retrieves the second post for each category. etc.

I'm just wondering if someone has a better solution for this. I don't really mind doing 1+N queries for that, but for curiosity and general SQL knowledge, it would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance to whom can help me with this.

Comment: How do you determine what blog_post is the newest in each category?

Comment: With a date. But that's just ordering stuff, I was able to do it myself. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [**MySQL article**](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) on how to work with the top N things in arbitrarily complex groupings; it's good stuff. You can try this:

```
SET @counter = 0;
SET @category = '';

SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    @counter := IF(posts.category = @category, @counter + 1, 0) AS counter,
    @category := posts.category,
    posts.*
    FROM
      (
      SELECT
        *
        FROM test
        ORDER BY category, date DESC
      ) posts
) posts
HAVING counter < 2
```

Comment: Well, that's another very good answer. Both of you deserves a up-vote. Thank you.
Still thinking about who gonna win the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  id,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  datetime
                FROM    posts pi
                WHERE   pi.category = c.id
                ORDER BY
                        pi.category DESC, pi.datetime DESC, pi.id DESC
                LIMIT 1, 1
                ), '1900-01-01') AS post_datetime,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  id
                FROM    posts pi
                WHERE   pi.category = c.id
                ORDER BY
                        pi.category DESC, pi.datetime DESC, pi.id DESC
                LIMIT 1, 1
                ), 0) AS post_id
        FROM    category c
        ) q
JOIN    posts p
ON      p.category <= q.id
        AND p.category >= q.id
        AND p.datetime >= q.post_datetime
        AND (p.datetime, p.id) >= (q.post_datetime, q.post_id)
```

Make an index on `posts (category, datetime, id)` for this to be fast.

Note the `p.category <= c.id AND p.category >= c.id` hack: this makes `MySQL` to use `Range checked for each record` which is more index efficient.

See this article in my blog for a similar problem:

- [**MySQL: emulating ROW_NUMBER with multiple ORDER BY conditions**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/14/mysql-emulating-row_number-with-multiple-order-by-conditions/)

Comment: Awesome, would this work even for categories where I have only 1 post? Wouldn't the limit excludes those posts?

Comment: This just get much complicated! I choosed the solution from John Feminella, which is much easier to understand and extend (if my M change).

Comment: John's solution is nice and quite efficient if you have many categories. However, if you have few categories but many post in each category, this solutions is more efficient. If you have less than `1,000` posts, you won't even notice the difference.

Comment: Ok, I'll dig into it for my personal knowledge when I'll have more time. Right now, I just see some strange magic, the second Coalesce looks like "(SELECT datetime) as post_id" and I'm a bit lost.

Comment: `@Savageman`: it's was a very powerful magic before I changed it to `SELECT id` :)