# How to get top 3 frequencies in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate

In MySQL I have a table called "meanings" with three columns:

- "person" (int),
- "word" (byte, 16 possible values)
- "meaning" (byte, 26 possible values).

A person assigns one or more meanings to **each** word:

```
person word meaning
-------------------
1      1    4
1      2    19
1      2    7  <-- Note: second meaning for word 2
1      3    5
...
1      16   2
```

Then another person, and so on. There will be thousands of persons.

I need to find for each of the 16 words the top three meanings (with their frequencies). Something like:

```
+--------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Word   | 1st Most Ranked | 2nd Most Ranked  | 3rd Most Ranked |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | meaning 5 (35%) | meaning 19 (22%) | meaning 2 (13%) |
| 2      | meaning 8 (57%) | meaning 1 (18%)  | meaning 22 (7%) |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

...

Is it possible to solve this with a single MySQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you group by word and meaning, you can easily get the % of people who use each word/meaning combination out of the dataset.

In order to limit the number of meanings for each word returned, you will need create some sort of filter per word/meaning combination.

Seems like you just want the answer to your homework, so I wont post more than this, but this should be enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: For the first part, google how to make a frequency distribution query.  For the second part, join the frequency distribution query with your filter query.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do

```
 SELECT * FROM words WHERE word = 2 ORDER BY meaning DESC LIMIT 3
```

But this is cheating since you need to create a loop.
Im working on a better solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe [the problem I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907534/retrieve-2-last-posts-for-each-category) a while ago looks similar. I ended up with the @counter thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Note about the problem**

Let's suppose there is only one person, who says:

```
+--------+----------------+
| Person | Word | Meaning |
+--------+----------------+
| 1      | 1    | 7       |
| 1      | 1    | 3       |
| 1      | 2    | 8       |
+--------+----------------+
```

The report should read:

```
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Word   | 1st Most Ranked  | 2nd Most Ranked  | 3rd Most Ranked |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | meaning 7 (100%) | meaning 3 (100%) | NULL            |
| 2      | meaning 8 (100%) | NULL             | NULL            |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

The following is not OK (50% frequency is absurd in a population of one person):

```
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Word   | 1st Most Ranked  | 2nd Most Ranked  | 3rd Most Ranked |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| 1      | meaning 7  (50%) | meaning 3  (50%) | NULL            |
| 2      | meaning 8 (100%) | NULL             | NULL            |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

The intended meaning of the frequencies is "How many people think this meaning corresponds to that word"?

So it's not merely about counting "cases", but about counting *persons* in the table.