# Best way to construct this query?

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

I have two tables set up similar to this (simplified for the quest):

actions-

```
id - user_id - action - time
```

users -

```
id - name
```

I want to output the latest action for each user. I have no idea how to go about it.

I'm not great with SQL, but from what I've looked up, it should look something like the following. not sure though.

```
SELECT `users`.`name`, *
FROM users, actions
JOIN < not sure what to put here >
ORDER BY `actions`.`time` DESC
< only one per user_id >
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, an anwser has already been accepted, but you have some nice lecture over there if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907534/retrieve-2-last-posts-for-each-category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users JOIN actions ON actions.id=(SELECT id FROM actions WHERE user_id=users.id ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Any specific reason you're using a subquery? Looks a bit complicated for the job at hand, no?

Comment: Mostly SQL ignorance, I use subqueries all the time when I probably shouldn't :). If there's a better way you should post it as a separate answer

Comment: Well, honoustly, I'm no SQL guru either... I thought you might have some genious reason as to why you'ld do it this way. ;-)

Comment: Oh. In that case, I did. A fantastically genius reason that would take pages and pages of complicated formulas to explain

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a groupwise max - please refer to examples here http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/

here's an example i did for somone else which is similar to your requirements:

http://pastie.org/925108

```
select
 u.user_id,
 u.username,
 latest.comment_id
from
 users u
left outer join
(
  select
   max(comment_id) as comment_id,
   user_id
  from
   user_comment
  group by
   user_id
 ) latest on u.user_id = latest.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

select u.name, a.action, a.time

from user u, action a

where u.id = a.user_id

and a.time in (select max(time) from action where user_id = u.user_id group by user_id )

note untested - but this should be the pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table (ID Int, User_ID, Time DateTime)

-- This gets the latest entry for each user
INSERT INTO @Table (ID, User_ID, Time)
SELECT ID, User_ID, MAX(TIME)
FROM actions z
INNER JOIN users x on x.ID = z.ID
GROUP BY z. userID

-- Join to get resulting action
SELECT z.user_ID, z.Action
FROM actions z 
INNER JOIN @Table x on x.ID = z.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the greatest-n-per-group problem that comes up frequently on Stack Overflow.  Follow the tag for dozens of other posts on this problem.

Here's how to do it in MySQL given your schema with no subqueries and no `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT u.*, a1.*
FROM users u JOIN actions a1 ON (u.id = a1.user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN actions a2 ON (u.id = a2.user_id AND a1.time < a2.time)
WHERE a2.id IS NULL;
```

In other words, show the user with her action such that if we search for another action with the same user and a later time, we find none.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the following will be works

```
WITH GetMaxTimePerUser (user_id, time) (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(time)
    FROM actions
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT u.name, a.action, amax.time
FROM actions AS a
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id=a.user_id
    INNER JOIN GetMaxTimePerUser AS u_maxtime ON u_maxtime.user_id=u.id
WHERE a.time=u_maxtime.time
```

Usage of temporary named result set (common table expression or CTE) without subqueries and OUTER JOIN is the way best opened for query optimization. (CTE is something like a VIEW but existing only virtual or inline)