# Get the n last entries from each category

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a system that has Blog, BlogEntry and Category. Category has many blogs and BlogEntry belongs to a blog.

I have a front page which displayes the latest blog entries. I would like to get the latest (say 5 latest) blog entries for each category so there is a equal share of categories on the front page at any given time (fashion and "pink blogers" are posting a lot. Two times a day at minimum!)

It is a Rails app and uses kaminari for pagination so I obviously would prefer a solution that supports kaminari (a activerecord::relation being returned).

I'm looking for something like this: [Retrieve 2 last posts for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907534/retrieve-2-last-posts-for-each-category). But rails/ActiveRecord spesific. 
I could possibly take the sql from that answer and make it fit my database scheme but I think that would only return an array and not an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Is what I'm looking for even possible?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: why do you need to return a scope if you're only displaying a predetermined number of results? you won't need to paginate it will you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use named scopes to filter blogs based on when they're published.

```
scope :recent, lambda { where('created_at >= ?', Time.current) }
scope :recent, lambda { order("created_at DESC") }
scope :recent, conditions: ["category = "blog" and created_at < ?", Time.now]
```