# Doctrine 2, Getting the last n articles for each category

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 entities, Article and Category, with a ManyToOne relation owned by Article and i want is to get the last 4 articles for each category.

If i was working with MySQL, the solution would be here "[Retrieve 2 last posts for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907534/retrieve-2-last-posts-for-each-category)", but unfortunately i'm working with DOCTRINE2 and DQL, I really don't know how to translate the two query in the answer to get the same result with DOCTRINE2.

Thanks in advance to whom can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If working with Doctrine Query Language or Query Builder will be difficult to you, then you can write your pure query and call it in your repository class like this:

```
public function fetchSomeRecordFromMyTable()
{
    $sql = 'MY PURE MYSQl QUERY';

    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $connection->execute();

    return $connection->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```