# Using Doctrine2: How to do a nested query with QueryBuilder?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am trying to do a nested query with the Doctrine2 QueryBuilder class that does something like this normal Sql query:

```
SELECT e.name, c.name
FROM
employee AS e
LEFT JOIN
    (task as t
     INNER JOIN customer AS c
     ON t.id = c.task_id)
ON e.id = t.employee_id
```

Is there any way to nest JOIN clauses like that in Symfony/Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's a little bit hard to build a query with queryBuilder or queryLanguage, In such cases I usually use pure PDO syntax to get my records. Here is my [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979351/doctrine-2-getting-the-last-n-articles-for-each-category/24979708#24979708) to such a task..

I'm also including the sample code here:

```
public function fetchSomeRecordFromMyTable()
{
    $sql = 'MY PURE MYSQl QUERY';

    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $connection->execute();

    return $connection->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: But I do need an array of objects as a result. I am atm trying to fiddle around with the ResultSetMappingBuilder (my actual sql query has 1xLeft Join and 3xInner Joins), but I'd obviously prefer to just use the QueryBuilder.